# Why installation rolls back at the end?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Our organization uses Wix Toolset to create an installation package for one of our applications (64-bit). Our installation  of old version of the product (which is 32-bit) is created using InstallShield. We have a requirement - when we install the new version (WiX install, 64-bit), if the old version is present (InstallShield - 32-bit), this needs to be uninstalled during the installation process. We are using same upgrade code in both installations.

Behaviour 1 - (When we are using same upgrade code) - Installation goes towards the end (created all application shortcuts), then throws an error '[AppName] Setup Wizard ended prematurely' and rollback installation.

Behaviour 2 - (When we are using different upgrade code) - As expected both applications exists after installation.

Anybody faced similar issue? How to solve this? I am stuck with this issue for last 3 days!

[Update] I am using Bootstrapper and logging is enabled by default. Please find below some extract from the log file. At the end, you can see a fatal error with return value 3.

```
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:340]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Readme,,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:340]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Publisher,Value=Future Fibre Technologies,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:341]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:341]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:341]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:341]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=ModifyPath,Value=#%MsiExec.exe /I{3D7E14A8-61BB-41EE-9FEB-2A0272B730C4},)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:341]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:341]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:341]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=InstallSource,Value=\\COMP_Name\Install\Testing\Software\AppName\v1.22.5\,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:341]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=InstallLocation,Value=C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\AppName\,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:341]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=InstallDate,Value=20161026,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=HelpTelephone,Value= ,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=HelpLink,Value=#%http://www.abc.com.au,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=DisplayVersion,Value=x.yy.0050,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Contact,Value= ,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Comments,Value= ,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=AuthorizedCDFPrefix,,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\8A41E7D3BB16EE14F9BEA220277B034C\InstallProperties,SecurityDescriptor=BinaryData,BinaryType=1,,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Language,Value=#1033,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:342]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Version,Value=#18219058,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=WindowsInstaller,Value=#1,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=VersionMinor,Value=#22,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=VersionMajor,Value=#1,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=URLUpdateInfo,Value=http://www.abc.com.au,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=URLInfoAbout,Value=http://www.abc.com.au,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=UninstallString,Value=#%MsiExec.exe /I{3D7E14A8-61BB-41EE-9FEB-2A0272B730C4},)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=EstimatedSize,Value=#53956,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Size,,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Readme,,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Publisher,Value=Future Fibre Technologies,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=ModifyPath,Value=#%MsiExec.exe /I{3D7E14A8-61BB-41EE-9FEB-2A0272B730C4},)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:343]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=LocalPackage,Value=C:\Windows\Installer\37e30.msi,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=InstallSource,Value=\\COMP_NAME\Install\Testing\Software\Application\vx.yy.z\,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=InstallLocation,Value=C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\AppName\,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=InstallDate,Value=20161026,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=HelpTelephone,Value= ,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=HelpLink,Value=#%http://www.abc.com.au,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=DisplayVersion,Value=1.22.0050,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Contact,Value= ,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Comments,Value= ,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=AuthorizedCDFPrefix,,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\TempPackages,,BinaryType=1,,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegRemoveValue(Name=C:\Windows\Installer\37e30.msi,Value=#0,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegRemoveKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\TempPackages 3: 2 
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\8A41E7D3BB16EE14F9BEA220277B034C\Transforms,,BinaryType=1,,)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: RegRemoveKey()
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\8A41E7D3BB16EE14F9BEA220277B034C\Transforms 3: 2 
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Executing op: End(Checksum=0,ProgressTotalHDWord=0,ProgressTotalLDWord=0)
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:344]: Error in rollback skipped.  Return: 5
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:345]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:346]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:347]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (A0:58) [10:08:56:347]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (s) (A0:5C) [10:08:56:347]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (c) (C8:7C) [10:08:56:363]: Back from server. Return value: 1603
MSI (c) (C8:7C) [10:08:56:363]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (C8:7C) [10:08:56:364]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 10:08:56: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (C8:7C) [10:08:56:364]: Doing action: FatalError
Action 10:08:56: FatalError. 
Action start 10:08:56: FatalError.
Action 10:08:56: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 10:08:57: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 10:08:57: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(C): DiskPrompt = [1]
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {03599145-22C5-4253-8D9A-78A05166A71F}
Property(C): WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED = #394254
Property(C): LicenseAccepted = 1
```

Update - Install Execute Sequence:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='StopAppService' Before='InstallValidate'/>
  <Custom Action='StopApplicationMonitor' After='InstallValidate'/>
  <Custom Action='BackupConfigFile' After='StopApplicationMonitor'>
    UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE OR REMOVE="ALL"
  </Custom>
  <Custom Action='ImportConfigFile' After='InstallFinalize'>Not Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action='PrepareStartApplicationMonitor' After='ImportConfigFile'>Not Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action='StartApplicationMonitor' After='PrepareStartApplicationMonitor'>Not Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Did you check your logs? you can find why the setup wizard ended prematurely with a command line. please use this one : `msiexec.exe /i c:\PathToYourMsi\YourMsi.msi /L*vx c:\PathToYourLog.txt` and give us the result. We will try to solve your first issue and after why the old installation is not deleted :)

Comment: Thank you very much, Fanny. I am using Bootstrapper and logging is enabled by default. Please find below some extract from the log file. At the end, you can see a fatal error with return value 3. I have updated the question with log info.

Comment: Hi Rajesh. I took a little look (and quick, I saw we have like 9 hours interval) So : check this post : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242963/wix-installer-uninstalls-but-not-installs-if-previous-version-is-installed). Could we see how you call your `ExecuteAction` custom action?

Comment: HI Fanny, Thank you for reviewing the log. I have updated question with <InstallExecuteSequence> with all custom actions. Everything seems to be happening. I can see, service started running after installation. But at the end installation is failing.